# ActiveRecord: find data from has_many relationships

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to find records that have a has_many relationship in rails using activerecord.  I am having a difficult time phrasing this question but here is what I would like to find:

```
has_many :var, :through => :line
```

The above line of code is included in a model.  I want to return records that have a certain :var associated with it.  So if, for example, :var = 1234, I'd like to return all records that have that associated with it.

Comment: has_many defines a relation between two tables (one to many), with 'through' even three tables.
It does not do a query on a record having certain values, you have the 'where' keyword and some others for that on an instance of your class.
I suggest you first do some reading on activecord.

Comment: I can say Order.product for example and get all products associated with that order.  I"d like to get orders that only have var of a specific value associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your main class is called `Order`, `line` is a belongs_to relation for Order, `vars` is a has_many relation for Line, and you are searching for the Var id

```
Order.joins(line: :vars).where('"vars"."id" = ?', 1234).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment i believe you need something like this

```
Order.where(:var => 1234)
```

or if you prefere plain sql

```
Order.where('var = 1234')
```

Activerecord has plenty of documentation on this, for example [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: The problem is var is not a field in the order table, maybe the only way to do this is to loop through all orders and check vars associated with it?

Comment: you will have to be more clear what you want, when you state :var = 1234 that is a field to me, so is it in an related table/class like line ?

Comment: I guess I didn't understand what the :through keyword meant in the has_many relationship.  I can get there by using the :var id in the line table given.  Thanks for the help.